# jQuery week calendar plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I have search the net and found nothing. Maybe someone here might have used something that google can't give me.

I wanted to use a week calendar. I am using [this](http://www.redredred.com.au/projects/jquery-week-calendar/) and have many difficulty in it. One is when my date and time are the same, they overlap in one another and only the one at the top can be clicked. I have tried to hack the codes but it feels like forever.

Any jQuery week calendar you can suggest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look [at this list](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/9-useful-jquery-calendar-and-date-picker-plugins-for-web-designers/) of jQuery-based calendars. I had good experience with [Datepicker](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker) which is highly customizable. Many of these can be customized to "week-view"

Comment: thank you for the reply. You said, "Many of these can be customized to 'week-view'". Can you please suggest one which I can use that is best for "week-view"? I want to take all that list but I'm really in a hurry now. Thank you again.

Comment: I would pick the very first one - Full calendar since it has weekly view and is well established http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Comment: I have picked the sixth one... jQuery Week Calendar

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#calendar').weekCalendar({
    timeslotsPerHour: 6, 
    // START SPLIT COLUMN
    allowCalEventOverlap: true, // Enable conflicting events
    overlapEventsSeparate: true, // Separate conflicting events
    // END SPLIT COLUMN
    daysToShow: 6, // Number of days to show initially
    switchDisplay: { '1 day': 1,  '3 next days': 3, 'work week': 5, 'full week': 6}, // Selector for number of days to be shown
    firstDayOfWeek : 1, // Sets the beginning of the week as Monday
    businessHours :{start: 7, end: 23, limitDisplay: true}, // Limits the time shown
    data: {
    events: eventData
    }
});
```

The section marked as "split column" enables the split column and shows both conflicting events.